# Why does not ContourPlot provide double roots?

Tags: plotting

Why ContourPlot does not give double roots? Here is a simple example.

`ContourPlot[(x-1)^2 (y - 3)^2 == 0, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 6}]`

If I have a much more complicated equation in which zeros are double roots, how can I identify them?

Comment: `ContourPlot` can't plot anything if the equation never crosses 0.

Comment: @ktm It does equal zero at $x=1$ and $y=3$.

Comment: But it does not cross $0$.

Comment: @ktm.  Now I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ContourPlot[(x - 1)^2 (y - 3)^2,
 {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 6},
 Contours -> 10.0^Range[-2, 1],
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 Exclusions -> {x == 1, y == 3},
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1/4], Red]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach:`RegionPlot` + [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html)

```
RegionPlot @ ImplicitRegion[(x - 1)^2 (y - 3)^2 == 0, {{x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 6}}]
```

[image]